# Is the intersection of two Caccioppoli (i.e. finite perimeter) sets Caccioppoli?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, geometric-measure-theory

Recall that we say that a bounded measurable set $S\subset\mathbb R^n$ is said to be *Caccioppoli* if the indicator function $1_S$ is BV, and we set
$$
\operatorname{perim}(S)=\| \nabla 1_S\|_{TV}
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_{TV}$ denotes the total variation. So, if $S$ and $T$ are Caccioppoli sets, is it known whether $S\cap T$ is Caccioppoli?

Comment: You might be interested in the following excellent book where you can find the affirmative answer to your question (Lemma 12.22) and much more. Francesco Maggi: Sets of finite perimeter and geometric variational problems, 2012.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**That is true.** Caccioppoli sets are also known as sets of finite perimeter.

> **Theorem.** *Suppose $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ vanishes outside the unit cube $[0,1]^n$. For $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ consider the function
>   $V_if(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n)=
>  V_0^1f(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},\cdot,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n)$, i.e. the
>   (essential) variation of the one dimensional sections. Then $f\in
>  BV(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if and only if for every $i$, $V_i\in
>  L^1([0,1]^{n-1}$).*

This is Theorem 5.3.5 in:

**W. P. Ziemer**,  *Weakly differentiable functions. Sobolev spaces and functions of bounded variation.* Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 120. Springer-Verlag, New York, 1989.

Basically it is a characterization of the functions of bounded variation by one dimensional slices.

If $h_1,h_2$ are characteristic functions of sets in $[0,1]$, then $V_0^1(h_1h_2)\leq V_0^1h_1+V_0^1 h_2$, see the proof of Theorem 2 in http://mathonline.wikidot.com/multiples-and-products-of-functions-of-bounded-variation. Now if $S$ and $T$ are Caccioppoli sets cotained in the unit cube, the characteristic functions $\chi_S$ and $\chi_T$ have bounded variation and the one dimensional result mentioned here shows that
$$
V_i(\chi_S\chi_T)\leq V_i(\chi_S)+V_i(\chi_T)\in L^1([0,1]^{n-1}).
$$
That implies that $\chi_S\chi_T=\chi_{S\cap T}$ has bounded variation so $S\cap T$ is a Caccioppoli set.

I assumed here that the sets are contained in the unit cube, but the argument applies to any bounded set.

Another answer is provided in a comment by Manfred Sauter (see above).

Answer (score 5):

Why not indulge in some overkill:

> **Theorem (cf. Federer, Theorem 4.5.11).** Let $\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}A\subset\RR^n$ be measurable with finite n-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Then $A$ has finite perimeter iff $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial^* A)<\infty$.

Here $\mathcal{H}^s$ denotes the $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure and $\partial^*A\subset\RR^n$ the measure-theoretic boundary of $A$. The latter is determined by
$$
x\in\RR^n\setminus\partial^*A \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \lim_{r\to 0+}\frac{\mathcal{H}^n(A\cap B(x,r))}{\mathcal{H}^n(B(x,r))}\in\{0,1\}.
$$
In other words, $x\in\partial^*A$ iff $A$ does not have Lebesgue density $0$ or $1$ at $x$.

By Federer's theorem it suffices to show that $\partial^*(S\cap T)\subset\partial^*S\cup\partial^*T$, or equivalently, $$(\RR^n\setminus\partial^*S)\cap(\RR^n\setminus\partial^*T)\subset\RR^n\setminus\partial^*(S\cap T).$$

The rest is elementary. Let $x$ be an element of the left hand side. Clearly, if $S$ or $T$ has density $0$ at $x$, then $S\cap T$ has density $0$ at $x$. So suppose both $S$ and $T$ have density $1$ at $x$. But as
$$(S\cap B(x,r))\setminus (B(x,r)\setminus T) = S\cap T\cap B(x,r),$$
also $S\cap T$ has density $1$ at $z$.  So $x$ is an element of the right hand side.

Comment: You should include your reference to Lemma 12.22 in the book by Francesco Maggi in your answer. Comments are not as easily seen as answers.

Comment: Hi Manfred, apologies for commenting on such an old thread. I have a quick question: Federer's theorem is stated in terms of $\mathscr{I}^{n-1}_1$ instead of the Hausdorff measure. Is his statement equivalent to yours? PS: He defines $\mathscr{I}^{m}_t$ in 2.10.5, and calls it the 'm-dimensional integral-geometric measure with exponent $t$', but I'm not familiar with the concept.

Comment: @LeoMoos Hi Leo! The problem is that Federer's result is actually even more awesome than what I quote. In 2.10.6 it is noted that m-dimensional Hausdorff measure is larger than a constant times the m-dimensional integral-geometric measure. This shows that the condition is sufficient, which is the more interesting implication. Theorem 4.5.11 in Federer characterizes the sets of _locally_ finite perimeter. Since above we use the condition without intersecting with compact sets, we can actually omit the _locally_, see also the Gauss-Green Theorem 4.5.6.

Comment: I hope this resolves your concerns. (I have also added the previously omitted precise assumptions on the set $A$.) If you are interested in the details and prefer a more down-to-earth exposition you can have a look at Section 5.11 of the book _Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions_ by Evans, Gariepy, where the locally finite version of the above result is proved.

Answer (score 4):

**The intersection of two Caccioppoli sets is again a Caccioppoli set**: as Piotr Hajlasz points out, a Caccioppoli set is simply a set of finite perimeter therefore the (standard) proof I report below is based on the following, slightly more general, definition of the (relative) perimeter of a set.

**Definition**. Let $S$ a Lebesgue measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For any open subset $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ the *perimeter of* $S$ *in* $\Omega$, denoted as $P(S,\Omega)$, is the variation of $\chi_S$ in $\Omega$ i.e.
\begin{split}
P(S,\Omega)&=\sup\left\{\int_S \mathrm{div}\varphi\,\mathrm{d}x\,:\,\varphi\in [C_c^1(\Omega)]^n, \|\varphi\|_\infty\leq1\right\}\\
& =\| \nabla (\chi_{S\cap\Omega})\|_{TV}=TV(S,\Omega)
\end{split}
The perimeter so defined is a lower-semicontinuous set function which is additive respect to the argument $\Omega$.

**Theorem**. Let $S$ and $T$ two Lebesgue measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$: then, for any open set $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$
$$
P(S\cup T,\Omega)+P(S\cap T,\Omega)\leq P(S,\Omega) + P(T,\Omega)
$$
**Proof**. We can choose two smooth sequences of functions $\{s_k\}, \{t_k\}$ in $C^\infty(\Omega)$ converging respectively to $\chi_S$ and $\chi_T$ in $L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$, for example by using partitions of unity, and such that
$$
0\leq s_k\leq 1\quad 0\leq t_k \leq 1,
$$
and
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_\Omega |\nabla s_k|\mathrm{d}x=P(S,\Omega)\quad
\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_\Omega |\nabla t_k|\mathrm{d}x=P(T,\Omega)
$$
Now since $s_kt_k\to\chi_{S\cap T}$ and $s_k+t_k-s_kt_k\to\chi_{S\cup T}$, the theorem follows by passing to the limit for $k\to\infty$ in the following elementary inequality
$$
\int_\Omega |\nabla (s_kt_k)|\mathrm{d}x+\int_\Omega |\nabla (s_k+t_k-s_kt_k)|\mathrm{d}x \leq
\int_\Omega |\nabla s_k|\mathrm{d}x+ 
\int_\Omega |\nabla t_k|\mathrm{d}x\quad\blacksquare
$$
An immediate consequence of this theorem is the following corollary, which includes the sought for answer to the posed question.

**Corollary**. If $S$ and $T$ are Caccioppoli sets, so are $S\cup T$ and $S \cap T$.

**Notes**

- The proof is taken almost verbatim from the wonderful book of Ambrosio, Fusco and Pallara ([1], §3.3 p. 144): De Giorgi, Colombini and Piccinini ([2], §1.3 pp.18-19) prove the same result in a different way and assuming from the start that $S$ and $T$ are Caccioppoli sets.
- A direct proof of the result $P(S),P(T)<\infty\Rightarrow P(S\cap T)<\infty$ is presented by Gurtin, Williams and Ziemer ([3], p. 6) and is based on lattice and measure theoretical considerations: in fact, it is worth noting that this property of Caccioppoli sets make them very important in the formal definition of the concept of *body* in the modern rational continuum mechanics.
- It is perhaps also worth to point out that the property of *BV* functions used by Piotr Hajlasz is in reality their original definition as conceived by Lamberto Cesari back in 1936.

[1] Ambrosio, Luigi; Fusco, Nicola; Pallara, Diego (2000). *Functions of bounded variation and free discontinuity problems*. Oxford Mathematical Monographs. New York and Oxford: The Clarendon Press/Oxford University Press, New York, pp. xviii+434, ISBN 0-19-850245-1, [MR1857292](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1857292), [Zbl 0957.49001](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0957.49001).

[2] De Giorgi, Ennio; Colombini, Ferruccio; Piccinini, Livio (1972), *Frontiere orientate di misura minima e questioni collegate* [Oriented boundaries of minimal measure and related questions], Quaderni (in Italian), Pisa: Edizioni della Normale, pp. 180, [MR0493669](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0493669), [Zbl 0296.49031](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0296.49031).

[3] Gurtin, M. E.; Williams, W. O. & Ziemer, W. P., "[Geometric measure theory and the axioms of continuum thermodynamics](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00250730)", Archive for Rational Mechanics and Analysis, 1986, 92, 1-22, [MR816619](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0816619), [Zbl 0599.73002](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0599.73002).