# What's the derivative of the characteristic function of the intersection of two Caccioppoli sets?

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, minimal-surfaces

Suppose that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain. A set $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$  is called a Caccioppoli set if $\sup\left\{ \int_{\Omega'} \chi_{E} \operatorname{div}(X) \, dx\right\}< \infty$ for any $\Omega' \subset \subset \Omega$, where $\sup$ is taken over all vector field $X$ with compact support in $\Omega'$ and $|X| \le 1$.  The derivative of $\chi_E$, $D\chi_E$, a vector-valued Radon measure,  is defined to be $\int_\Omega \chi_E \operatorname{div}(X) \, dx = \int_\Omega \left<X, D\chi_E\right>$ for all compactly supported vector field $X$. Now I have a question: If $E, F$ are Caccioppoli sets, then what's $D(\chi_{E\cap F})$? Does it hold that $D(\chi_{E\cap F})=\chi_E D\chi_F + \chi_FD\chi_E$?

Comment: First a [related Q&A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296350/is-the-intersection-of-two-caccioppoli-i-e-finite-perimeter-sets-caccioppoli). Then hint for an answer: your formula for the derivative is consequence of the fact that $\chi_{E\cap F} = \chi_E\cdot\chi_F$ and of the chain rule for $BV$ functions.